# Disable showing icon next to file name type

Tags: icons

I have css that shows icon for file types but I want to disable it for part of a page. I'm clueless on how to accomplish this.
My current css is:

```
a[href$=".pdf"] {
background: url('../images/pdficon_small.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.
I did try

```
<div class> with img.icon-none }  display: none;}
```

but it didn't work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I created a div class called icon-hidden and this css:

```
.icon-hidden  a[href$=".pdf"] {
background: none;}
```

It works.